# Get current date onClick function

Tags: jquery

I want to get start date and end date when click the buttons.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#start_time').click(function(){
$('#end_time').show();
$('#start_time').hide();
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'startdate',
    name: 'startdate',
    value: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>'
}).appendTo('form')
$('#show_sdate').text($('#startdate').val());
});

$('#end_time').click(function(){
$('#start_time').show();
$('#end_time').hide();
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'enddate',
    name: 'enddate',
    value: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>'
}).appendTo('form')
$('#show_edate').text($('#enddate').val());
});
</script>
```

When I click end_time, I am getting the result like this

Start Time: 2014-06-24 07:34:57
End Time:   2014-06-24 07:34:57

How to get current date?
Thanks.

Comment: without html how can we provide the solution?

Comment: You have to remove `php` tag from your question since it isn't related to `php`

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date using datepicker method:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date());
```